# Why is my recursive CTE so much slower on Azure SQL?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, cte, recursive

I have this simple recursive CTE for a hierarchy of folders and their paths:

```
WITH paths AS (
    SELECT Id, ParentId, Name AS [Path] FROM Folders
    WHERE ParentId IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT f.Id, f.ParentId, [Path] + '/' + f.Name FROM Folders f
    JOIN paths on f.ParentId = paths.Id
)
SELECT Id, [Path] from paths
WHERE Id = @FolderId
```

On my local SQL Server express, it runs in 35 ms no problem. On my Azure SQL database, it occasionally takes around 400 ms. The Azure SQL table only has around 2000 rows, and other simple queries only take around 80ms. I have indexes on Id and ParentId. My app can make this query very frequently and it's annoying to have to wait half a second or more every time. Here are screenshots of the two separate plans, no idea why they are different:

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Hky4zASAI
[image: SQL Express]

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=H17LfRHAU
[image: Azure SQL]

Is Azure SQL just slower?

EDIT: this has nothing to do with Azure SQL, the table there was a lot bigger than my test.

Comment: could you please share actual execution plans using - https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ ? Do you have exactly the same table structure and data on local server and in Azure?

Comment: @Nikita I am using datagrip and i'm not sure how to get query plan as XML for this tool. The tables' schema are the same, but i only have a few dozen rows locally

Comment: @Nikita nvm i figured it out and added the links

Comment: did you compare query performance using the same data on both servers?

Comment: no, it's only a few thousand rows on the azure server and the hierarchy is never more than 4 folders deep. I don't think it should make that much difference.

Comment: but actually your Azure table is 100 times larger and you compare the query agains few rows vs query against two thousands of them. Please check how fast does it work locally with the sam data.

Comment: dang you're right, with 2000  rows locally it takes 500+ ms as well. I didn't know recursive CTEs were soooo slow. that sux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked your query again and it seems you can rewrite it this way:

```
WITH paths AS (
    SELECT Id, ParentId, Name AS [Path] FROM Folders
    WHERE Id = @FolderId

    UNION ALL

    SELECT f.Id, f.ParentId, f.Name  + '/' + [Path] FROM Folders f
    JOIN paths on paths.ParentId = f.Id
    )
SELECT @FolderId AS Id, [Path] from paths
WHERE ParentId IS NULL
```

Comment: wow! super fast this way! TY!!! 80 ms

Comment: @EricB It works faster because it works in "reverse" way (it starts with required folder and check its parent and parent of the parent and so on). Your original query generates the whole hierarchy - it goes from the root through the whole tree and creates rows with full path for each folder and then apply filter to them to show you the only one row you need.